# java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express in my laptop and tried to run a sample java program as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Ex2 {
  Connection con;
  Statement st;
  ResultSet rs;
  public Ex2(String query){
      System.out.println("IN Const1");
    try{
        System.out.println("IN try");
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String dbName = "HOME";
        String user = "sa";
        String password = "JUL@2012";
        //the name of my SQL SERVER 2005 instance
        String SqlServerInstance = "SQLEXPRESS";
        String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433";
        url = url + "/" + dbName;
        url = url + ";" + SqlServerInstance;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("nach DriverManager");
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeQuery(query);
        rs = st.getResultSet();
       while ( rs.next() ){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(0));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] argv){
      System.out.println("IN MAIN");
    Ex2 test = new Ex2("SELECT * FROM HOME.dbo.employee;");
  }
}*
```

and getting the following error log in the console:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
    at Ex2.<init>(Ex2.java:22)
    at Ex2.main(Ex2.java:43)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:516)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:307)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:257)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:311)
Exception: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect
    ... 6 more
```

When I checked the sql server configuration manager the services SQL Server and SQL Server Browser are running.

I have been googling for the last two days and struggle to fix this issue and couldn't. So please help me.